# Yii2 yii2mod/yii2-rbac

Tags: yii2, rbac

I try to understand how it works - no way
I only can see the routes beginning with /rbac/ .. and some with /gridview/ ... and /dynagrid/ ...
But no route related to my contoller actions
I thought that **yii2mod/yii2-rbac** worked like RBAC in Yii1 where I had permissions defined and checked in controller.

When - as before - I insert something like this :

```
INSERT INTO `auth_item` (`name`, `type`, `description`, `rule_name`, `data`) VALUES ('createCompany', 0, 'createCompany', NULL, 'N;');
```

and assign it to a user Admin it appears as a permission and not as a route in the permission view of Admin (rbac/permission/view/Admin)

The readme file did not help me - so how can I use yii2mod/yii2-rbac ?

Comment: Are you trying to understand the rbac mechanism of yii2? Still want to know the separate package yii2mod/yii2-rbac?

Comment: depends - will take the one I can understand

Answer (score 1):

The **yii2mod/yii2-rbac** package what it ***provides is a web interface***, but it **is not** an alternative to the native implementation of the RBAC in Yii2:

> Yii2-RBAC provides a web interface for advanced access control and
>   includes following features:
>
> - Allows CRUD operations for roles, permissions, rules
> - Allows to assign multiple roles or permissions to the user
> - Allows to create console migrations
> - Integrated with [yii2mod/base](https://github.com/yii2mod/base)

The base of this package is the RBAC Yii2 that can review part of its implementation [here](https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-rbac/blob/master/models/AssignmentModel.php#L44) (only as an example).

Making a raw `INSERT` to the `auth_item` table does not make much sense as a way to understand how the RBAC works. The `auth_item` table keeps the records of the permissions and/or roles which are separated by types: 1=Role, 2=permission.

Installed and configured **yii2mod/yii2-rbac** in your project you could  enter the different options to create roles, permissions, routes and assign them to your users as they inidcan them:

```
http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=rbac/
http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=rbac/route
http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=rbac/permission
http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=rbac/role
http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=rbac/assignment
```

or if you have enabled pretty URLs, you may use the following URL:

```
http://localhost/path/to/index.php/rbac
http://localhost/path/to/index.php/rbac/route
http://localhost/path/to/index.php/rbac/permission
http://localhost/path/to/index.php/rbac/role
http://localhost/path/to/index.php/rbac/assignment
```

If you want to understand better how the YB2 RBAC works, you can review it from [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/framework/rbac).